# Я работаю с qt designer и хочу сделать калькулятор дробей. Не знаю как воспроизвести ответ?

Tags: python, pyqt5

это файл **lib.py**

```
class Fraction(object):

    def __init__(self, top: int, bottom: int):
        self.__top = top
        self.__bottom = bottom

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__top} / {self.__bottom}'

    def __add__(self, other):
        e1 = self.__top * other.__bottom
        e2 = self.__bottom * other.__top
        e = e1 + e2
        f = self.__bottom * other.__bottom
        return Fraction(e, f)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        e1 = self.__top * other.__bottom
        e2 = self.__bottom * other.__top
        e = e1 - e2
        f = self.__bottom * other.__bottom
        return Fraction(e, f)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        e1 = self.__top * other.__top
        e2 = self.__bottom * other.__bottom
        return Fraction(e1, e2)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        e1 = self.__top * other.__bottom
        e2 = self.__bottom * other.__top
        return Fraction(e1, e2)

    def reduce(self):
        if self.__top > self.__bottom:
            k = self.__top
        else:
            k = self.__bottom
        while k != 1:
            if self.__top % k == 0 and self.__bottom % k == 0:
                return f'{self.__top // k} / {self.__bottom // k}'
            else:
                k -= 1

    def get_top(self):
        return Fraction().__getattribute__('__top')

    def get_bottom(self):
        return Fraction().__getattribute__('__bottom')
```

---

это файл **gui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

from lib import Fraction


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__win = uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui')

    def show(self):
        self.set_slots()
        self.__win.show()

    def set_slots(self):
        self.__win.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.slot1)

    def slot1(self):
        a = int(self.__win.lineEdit.text())
        b = int(self.__win.lineEdit_2.text())
        c = int(self.__win.lineEdit_3.text())
        d = int(self.__win.lineEdit_4.text())
        s = self.__win.lineEdit_8.text()
        res1 = Fraction(a, b)
        res2 = Fraction(c, d)
        if s == '+':
            res = res1 + res2
            ind = res.split('/')
            mas = Fraction(ind[0], ind[1])
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{mas.get_top()}'),  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{mas.get_bottom()}'))
            # print(mas[0], mas[1])
        # QMessageBox.information(self, 'Заголовок', str())
        #     self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText('0')
        # QMessageBox.question(self, 'Заголовок', 'Вопрос?')
        # QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Заголовок', 'Предупреждение')
        # QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Заголовок', 'Ошибка')
```

---

это файл **main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from gui import MainWindow

import sys

from lib import *


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `MainWindow.ui`

Comment: Нет, вам не надо дублировать, то что уже есть, да еще и в ответе. Удалите  ваш ответ. Ниже вашего вопроса есть кнопка `править`, нажмите ее и в самом низу добавьте модуль `MainWindow.ui`, который создан в `QT Designer`

Comment: @S.Nick, я опубликовал вариант решения, но не могу опубликовать модуль MainWindow.ui так как не знаю как перевести окно с модулем в код

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно нашли решение, то так в ответе и напишите, что вопрос решен.   По поводу публикации, так ничего переводить в код не надо. Публикуется все одинаково, что модули  `.py` , что `.ui`

Answer (score 0):

это lib

class Fraction(object):

```
def __init__(self, top: int, bottom: int):
    self.__top = top
    self.__bottom = bottom

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f'{self.__top} / {self.__bottom}'

def __add__(self, other):
    e1 = self.__top * other.__bottom
    e2 = self.__bottom * other.__top
    e = e1 + e2
    f = self.__bottom * other.__bottom
    return Fraction(e, f)

def __sub__(self, other):
    e1 = self.__top * other.__bottom
    e2 = self.__bottom * other.__top
    e = e1 - e2
    f = self.__bottom * other.__bottom
    return Fraction(e, f)

def __mul__(self, other):
    e1 = self.__top * other.__top
    e2 = self.__bottom * other.__bottom
    return Fraction(e1, e2)

def __truediv__(self, other):
    e1 = self.__top * other.__bottom
    e2 = self.__bottom * other.__top
    return Fraction(e1, e2)

def reduce(self):
    if self.__top > self.__bottom:
        k = self.__top
    else:
        k = self.__bottom
    while k != 1:
        if self.__top % k == 0 and self.__bottom % k == 0:
            return f'{self.__top // k} / {self.__bottom // k}'
        else:
            k -= 1

def get_top(self):
    return self.__top

def get_bottom(self):
    return self.__bottom
```

это gui

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

from lib import Fraction

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.__win = uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui')

def show(self):
    self.set_slots()
    self.__win.show()

def set_slots(self):
    self.__win.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.slot1)

def slot1(self):
    a = int(self.__win.lineEdit.text())
    b = int(self.__win.lineEdit_2.text())
    c = int(self.__win.lineEdit_3.text())
    d = int(self.__win.lineEdit_4.text())
    s = self.__win.lineEdit_8.text()
    res1 = Fraction(a, b)
    res2 = Fraction(c, d)
    if s == '+':
        res = res1 + res2
        if res.get_top() > res.get_bottom():
            dom = res.get_top() // res.get_bottom()
            top = res.get_top() % res.get_bottom()
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{top}'),
                  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{res.get_bottom()}'))
            self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText(f'{dom}')
        else:
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{res.get_top()}'),
                  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{res.get_bottom()}'))
            self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText('0')
    if s == '-':
        res = res1 - res2
        if res.get_top() > res.get_bottom():
            dom = res.get_top() // res.get_bottom()
            top = res.get_top() % res.get_bottom()
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{top}'),
                  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{res.get_bottom()}'))
            self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText(f'{dom}')
        else:
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{res.get_top()}'),
                  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{res.get_bottom()}'))
            self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText('0')
    if s == '/':
        res = res1 / res2
        if res.get_top() > res.get_bottom():
            dom = res.get_top() // res.get_bottom()
            top = res.get_top() % res.get_bottom()
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{top}'),
                  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{res.get_bottom()}'))
            self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText(f'{dom}')
        else:
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{res.get_top()}'),
                  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{res.get_bottom()}'))
            self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText('0')
    if s == '*':
        res = res1 * res2
        if res.get_top() > res.get_bottom():
            dom = res.get_top() // res.get_bottom()
            top = res.get_top() % res.get_bottom()
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{top}'),
                  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{res.get_bottom()}'))
            self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText(f'{dom}')
        else:
            print(self.__win.lineEdit_5.setText(f'{res.get_top()}'),
                  self.__win.lineEdit_6.setText(f'{res.get_bottom()}'))
            self.__win.lineEdit_7.setText('0')
    # QMessageBox.information(self, 'Заголовок', str())
    # QMessageBox.question(self, 'Заголовок', 'Вопрос?')
    # QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Заголовок', 'Предупреждение')
    # QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Заголовок', 'Ошибка')
```